# Pull 15 digit order number to new column using the beginning 5 digit order ID

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have two columns(B&C) of order data that contain a diverse mix of letters and numbers and may or may not contain a specific 15 digit order number mixed in the cell in many different ways. The order number could be to the left middle or the right of the cell. All the order numbers have a specific 5 digit identifier(75 unique in total) that start each order number. 
Example of the 5 digit identifiers and a full 15 digit order ID

- 12018   **12018**0000000852
- 38003   **38003**0000003456
- C0009   **C0009**0000087652
- P0009   **P0009**0000378464
- A0010   **A0010**0000456321

Example of cell values that make getting the PO number difficult, some cells contain partial order numbers that are not usable and random text or number strings that can be smaller or shorter than 15 digits

- 540501/**12018**0000000852
- BO**A0010**0000456321 8054960602
- 86790865 /  /**38003**0000003456
- DSA1491799-000
- **38003**0000056

My end goal is to have a single column that lists just the 15 digit order numbers pulled from both B and C, anything more or less would just be blank. Would using a column of all 75 unique 5 digit order IDs help extract that order data.

Comment: If it's always the right-most 15 digits you're interested in you could use: `=RIGHT(Raw_Number, 15)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the 15 digit order number could be anywhere, left right or center, I added that to the main question just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the '5 digit identifiers' in column Z (starting in row 2) and the 'full 15 digit order ID' in column A starting in row 2 with an unused column in column B, open the VBE and paste hte following into a new module code sheet.

```
Sub digit_identifiers()
    Dim r As Long, v As Long, vDIDs As Variant, vDOIDs As Variant
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<~~set this worksheet properly!!
        vDIDs = .Range(.Cells(2, "Z"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp)).Value2
        vDOIDs = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
        .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "[color13]@"
        
        For r = LBound(vDOIDs, 1) To UBound(vDOIDs, 1)
            For v = LBound(vDIDs, 1) To UBound(vDIDs, 1)
                If CStr(vDOIDs(r, 1)) Like Chr(42) & CStr(vDIDs(v, 1)) & Chr(42) Then
                    'full 15 digit order ID
                    .Cells(1 + r, "B") = CStr(Mid(CStr(vDOIDs(r, 1)), InStr(1, CStr(vDOIDs(r, 1)), CStr(vDIDs(v, 1)), vbTextCompare), 15))
                    'alternate for just the 5 digit identifier
                    '.Cells(1 + r, "B") = CStr(vDIDs(v, 1))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next v
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the worksheet then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to Run the macro. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Pattern matching variant strings]

The order that you place the '5 digit identifiers' into column Z as may have an effect on the results. If '38003` is likely to produce a false positive match when the result should have been 'C0009', make sure that 'C0009' comes before '38003' in the order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there any way to get the entire 15 digit PO in column B assuming the next 10 digits to the right are the correct numbers?

Comment: *<sigh>* Sure. I thought you would have been able to handle that.

Comment: I might have been able to I am unable to test anything until work tomorrow and was eager to be done after frustrating attempts today and a newborn keeps me busy at home, thank you for your time